# List all files, showing file types terminal

Tags: command-line, files

I am doing a university assignment at the moment which specifies that I list the command to; List all files, showing file types.

I have searched high and low to try and find the correct command to achieve this, but have had no luck!

Would somebody be able to help me out by pointing me in the right direction or maybe telling me what command could do this?

Comment: read about the ls command

Comment: First, you need to define what you mean by "file type" - to a Windows user, that usually means a 'dot extension' on the filename, whereas in the *nix world it would more likely refer to the actual MIME type of the file (as determined by the `file` or `mimetype` commands).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> *"List all files, showing file types."*

To see all files in the current directory and their file type, try:

```
file ./*
```

Example:

```
$ file ./*
./apt.conf.d:                 directory
./listchanges.conf:           ASCII text
./preferences.d:              directory
./sources.list:               ASCII text
./sources.list.d:             directory
./trusted.gpg:                GPG key public ring
```

The above shows a human-readable form of the file type.  Alternatively, one can print the file's mime-type:

```
$ file --mime-type ./*
./apt.conf.d:                 inode/directory
./listchanges.conf:           text/plain
./preferences.d:              inode/directory
./sources.list:               text/plain
./sources.list.d:             inode/directory
./trusted.gpg:                application/x-gnupg-keyring
```

`file` does a cursory examination of the content of each file to determine its type.  The default output, as shown in both examples above, includes the file name and the file type.  For more information, see `man file`.

Comment: In addition to this answer let's say that you are looking just for HTML files, you would run something like:
file * | grep HTML

Comment: Ahem... In this case, my use was intended exactly as the output of the command. (Someone downloaded jpegs that returned a 404 html with wget or curl without properly adding exceptions)

Comment: Depending on your filename structure, file * may output the error file: invalid option -- '-'
This can be solved by running file ./* instead (safer too)

Comment: @LukeRehmann Thank you much.  Answer updated with `./`.